# Как при клике на миниатюру сделать ее фоном?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, background

Как при клике на миниатюру сделать ее фоном?

```css
html {
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.items {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items a {
  margin: .5em;
  opacity: .5;
}

.items a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.items img {
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="img/img01.jpg">
    <img src="img/img01.jpg">
    <img src="img/img01.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("a.thumb").click(function(e) {
    $("html").addClass("active");
    var background = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html.active").css({
      "background": '#222 url(' + background + ')',
      "background-attachment": "fixed",
      "background-size": "cover"
    });
    $("div.overlay").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background .5s ease;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .50;
}

.items {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items a {
  margin: .5em;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.items a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.items img {
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <a class="thumb" href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2427227/07734240-5437-4595-b08e-b86926b131ca/s1200"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2427227/07734240-5437-4595-b08e-b86926b131ca/s1200"></a>
    <a class="thumb" href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2435676/dda44a98-143d-468b-808d-5b5c8b00fbd8/s1200"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2435676/dda44a98-143d-468b-808d-5b5c8b00fbd8/s1200"></a>
    <a class="thumb" href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2349701/7f4bc856-9c1a-4615-ad13-b507e260a128/s1200"><img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2349701/7f4bc856-9c1a-4615-ad13-b507e260a128/s1200"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение на `javascript` без `jquery`:

```js
    let preinp = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
    let inp = preinp[0].querySelectorAll('img');
    inp.forEach(function (c) {
        c.onclick = function () {
            let src = c.getAttribute('src');
            let z = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
            document.body.style.background = 'url('+src+')no-repeat';
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
        }
    })
```

```css
    html,body {
        background: #222;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .items {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .items a {
        margin: .5em;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    .items a:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .items img {
        height: 100px;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="items">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTrTAH0P0Pq9vyQ1S0NPVfsf3Jib3LNdkkbtIaSSamnahRZUQS7">
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

По клику получаете значение src миниатюры и передаёте в качестве url фона:

```js
$('.items img').click(function(){
  $('html').css('background','url('+$(this).attr('src')+')');
});
```

```css
html {
background: #222;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.items {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
.items img {
height: 100px;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2376282/c17c9792-8ac4-4175-a06c-33b01379ad40/s1200">
    <img src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/12/14/328186349870573/sineva-linii-izgiby-prozrachnost-dvizhenie.jpg">
    <img src="https://img2.akspic.ru/image/113327-trava-drevesina-bambuk-stebel_rasteniya-zelenyj-3840x2160.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```